# Twitter bootstrap and Checkboxlist or Radiobutton list

Tags: css, checkboxlist, twitter-bootstrap

I got a markup like below and without any styling, the Twitetr Bootstrap css seems to mess something such that the checkbox falls below the label text.**What is the thing i got to change**

```
<ul >
    <li>
        <label>1<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>2<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[screenshot http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/3390/savec.jpg](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/3390/savec.jpg)

Comment: what are the relevant styles being applied?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

inputs-list doesn't seem to be a css class anymore. I used `class="nav nav-list"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "inputs-list" to your `<ul>`. Everything will magically work.

Comment: that was so awesome. it worked. So do i apply the same css rules to inputs that are grouped etc??

Comment: I suggest looking at Twitter's example page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ It has examples of most common scenarios.

Comment: Sorry to disturb u again but i got markup as below & the `span5` just goes below the `span11` u got any ideas? `<div class="row"><div class="span11"><h3 class="page-header">Title<small> small title</small></h3></div><div class="span4 alert-message block-message"><h3 class="page-header">Another Title<small>this drops below</small></h3></div></div>`